# Buck converter (TPS54331) oscillating

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, texas-instruments, step-down

I have designed and built a buck converter based on the TPS54331 which oscillates at 5.4kHz with an amplitude of 700mV peak-to-peak under a 1A load. I want to remove these oscillations.

Here is a scope picture of the problem (yellow = switch DC, blue = Vout AC):

[image]

The circuit has the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

What should I be looking for to solve this problem?

Update: Here is the relevant part of the PCB layout (back side is an uninterrupted ground plane):

[image]

Update 2: Labeled L1 in the PCB layout

Update 3: I also removed the load to bring the it into DCM mode and it produces the following saw tooth wave at the output (yellow=switch, purple=Vin, teal=Vout):

[image]

Comment: Could you add your PCB layout to the question?

Comment: Where is C9 and L1 located? Too busy graphics... What’s the ESR of your output caps? How’s BOOT and Vin pins looking on your scope during this event?

Comment: How are you measuring the switch voltage? Switching converters can be very sensitive to switched-node capacitance, and putting an oscilloscope probe there can mess things up quite a bit.

Comment: First thing I notice is poor decoupling. C4's negative return is awfully far away from GND pin 7.

Comment: My first thought would be that the compensation network (which is *highly* layout sensitive) is not quite right.

Comment: @winny: I labeled L1 in the PCB layout, C9 is located to the left of U4

Comment: @Hearth: I'm hooking into the inductor, although the oscillations were the same with only the Vout probe attached. Vin looks clean (some 100mV p-p triangle wave pattern of the switch frequency), BOOT I haven't probed yet (what should I be looking for there?)

Comment: @Unimportant: Agree, I should at least put a via down to the back plane if I can't relocate C4. That said, I wonder if it is likely it causes the problem at hand?

Comment: @PeterSmith: How can I validate if the design or layout of the compensation network isn't right? I tried probing the COMP pin but that affected the output a lot so I'm not sure how I can understand what's going on there

Comment: What's your switching frequency, anyway?

Comment: Switching frequency is 610kHz (according to my scope)

Comment: There is a pretty detailed description of the design of the compensation network. The device is a current mode device, which is sensitive to *variations in output current*, so oscillations at particular output current(s) would tend to implicate the compensation network,. Probing the COMP pin will add capacitive loading so it is not surprising that the operation changes when you do that. Adding a phase lead  capacitor across R10 (100pF might be a good start) will give added phase boost.

Comment: I just calculated the resistor for the compensation pole zero pair and I come up with 49k which is a *lot* larger than your 100 ohm part. See pages 20 and 21 of the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, I will try replacing R6 with a larger value to see how that affects the circuit

Comment: The typical values for the compensation capacitors would be closer to 1nF for C7 and less than 100pF for C8. This is all described in the compensation network design section.

Comment: Thanks! 5.4 kHz is very close to the LC crossover frequency of your output LC filter so compensation is the most likely candidate. But just to rule out the gate drive, can you check BOOT pin? Also, what’s your ESR?

Comment: Output caps are 0805 MLCC (CL21A226MAQNNNE), I assume they are quite low ESR but can't find the exact number in their datasheet. It is pretty likely that I messed up the calculations of the comp network, but just for my understanding: My current comp crossover frequency is about 900Hz, will I often run into these kind of problems if comp crossover frequency is lower than the output LC crossover frequency?